# Human Papillomavirus E7 (HR HPV16)

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, proteins, molecular-genetics, protein-binding

So there's a protein that binds to E7 viral protein, I want to remove a sub domain of the protein to see which exact domain the E7 binds to.

What is the procedure for this?

Edit: I believe the virus is HR HPV16. I need to know a method/procedure that can allow me to delete/mutate the NLS, CXXC ,BAH1 and BAH2 domains in the enzyme DNMT1

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Unfortunately your question is unclear as it stands. What virus are you talking about? When you say you want to remove the subdomain are you talking about work with the gene or the protein? And what do you mean by "What is the procedure?" How much work have you already done? What research have you done? We need to have that sort of information if we are to try and help you.

Comment: Thank you David :D I believe it is the HPV E7. And I am talking about work with the protein. I'm actually a bit confused myself. I will update as soon as I get more information

Comment: Oh and David, I sent you an email regarding further information on this. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Please do not send me personal emails. This is a question and and answer site. When someone makes their first post, it is flagged to older members of the list so that they can make suggestions, if necessary, for improving it. That is what I did to prevent your question being rejected and to incease the chances of your getting an answer. I personally shall not be answering as this is not my field of expertise.

Comment: Ahh I see. I apologize